# How do I multiply values of Multidimansional array that contain measurements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got a the next multidimensional array that contain measurements, in inches, for 3 boxes that determine the volume of a box

```
$box = array(
            array("Small Box", 12, 10, 2.5),
            array("Medium Box", 30, 20, 4),
            array("Large Box", 60, 40, 11.5)
        );
```

now my question is how do i multiple the value of the boxes to echo the volume of each box? So the result will be something like:
"The volume of the **Small Box** is: **300**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($box as $key => $value) {
  // assuming that values exists as depicted in question.
  $volume = ($value[1] * $value[2] * $value[3]);
  echo "Volume of " . $value[0] . " is " . $volume;
}
```

Comment: This helped me answering my code, Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `foreach` and iterate over the box array. Note though, if the order or a property is missing you might get unexpected results.

```
foreach ($box as $aBox){
    $iVolume = ($aBox[1] * $aBox[2] * $aBox[3]);
    echo "The volume of ".$aBox[0]." is: ".$iVolume;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your volume array for each box,

```
$box = array(
        array("Small Box", 12, 10, 2.5),
        array("Medium Box", 30, 20, 4),
        array("Large Box", 60, 40, 11.5)
    );
$dimArr = array_map("removeBoxName", $box);
$volumnArr = array_map("calculateVolume", $dimArr);
print_r($volumnArr);

// Common functions
function removeBoxName($arrBox) {
    array_shift($arrBox);
    return $arrBox;
}

function calculateVolume($arrBox) {
    return array_product($arrBox);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but total overhead for this task.